# ¿Cómo hacer una cabecera y los datos con un foreach en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo, php7

Estoy desarrollando un registro de datos y se están organizando por grupo, en la cabecera esta la fecha de su registro. Pero las fechas están insertada por cada fila de la tabla, por ejemplo en un grupo de 5 datos tienen la misma fecha y en el segundo grupo tienes 3 datos que tiene la misma fecha de este grupo, entonces como haría para mostrar solo la fecha x grupo como cabecera.

Aquí les dejo mi código.

```
$id_trabajador = $_POST['id_trabajador'];
$fecha_min = $_POST['i_fecha_devolu_ini'];
$fecha_nax = $_POST['i_fecha_devolu_fin'];
$emp = new Descargo_bar();
$reg = $emp->lista_insumos($id_trabajador,$fecha_min,$fecha_nax);

$tabla = '<table class="table table-striped table-responsive table-bordered">';
$tabla .= '<thead>'
            . '<tr class="info">'
                . '<th>Insumos</th>'
                . '<th>Und.Medida</th>'
                . '<th>Cant.Medida</th>'
            . '</tr>'
        . '</thead>';
foreach($reg as $cab){
    $tabla .= '<tbody>';
    $tabla .= '<tr>';
    $tabla .= '<td colspan="3" style="background-color: green;color: #fff;">'.$cab['FECHA_TRANSCURRIDO'].'</td>';    
    $tabla .= '</tr>';
foreach ($cab as $cup){ 
        $tabla .= '<tr>';
        $tabla .= '<td>'.$cup['V010NOMBRE'].'</td>';
        $tabla .= '<td>'.$cup['v012NOMBRE'].'</td>';
        $tabla .= '<td>'.round($cup['CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO_XINSUMO']).'</td>';
        $tabla .= '</tr>';
    }
$tabla .= '</tbody>';
}
$tabla .= '</table>';


echo $tabla;
```

Comment: No me queda claro que problema estás enfrentando. No parece que en tu código actual estés intentado resolver tu problema. Tal vez debas investigar primero como hacer tablas pivote. En mi opinión esta pregunta es muy amplia.

Answer (score 0):

Debes ordenar la consulta por fechas y establecer una condición cuando la fecha cambie.

```
$id_trabajador = $_POST['id_trabajador'];
$fecha_min = $_POST['i_fecha_devolu_ini'];
$fecha_nax = $_POST['i_fecha_devolu_fin'];
$emp = new Descargo_bar();
$reg = $emp->lista_insumos($id_trabajador, $fecha_min, $fecha_nax);

/*

 * suponiendo que realizas un order by por fecha
 *  */

$tabla = '<table>';

$fecha = null;
foreach ($reg as $i => $cab) {

  //En cada cambio de fecha creamos una cabecera
  if ($cab['FECHA_TRANSCURRIDO'] !== $fecha) {

    //En elprimer cambio no hay tbody que cerrar
    if ($fecha !== null) {

      //Cerramos el tbody del grupo anterior
      $tabla .= "</tbody>";
    }

    $fecha = $cab['FECHA_TRANSCURRIDO'];
    $tabla .= '' . '' . 'Insumos' . '' . '' . '' . '';
    //Creamos la cabecera
    $tabla .= "<thead>"
              . "<tr>"
                . "<th colspan='3'>{$fecha}</th>"
              . "</tr>"
              . "<tr>"
                . "<th>Insumos</th>"
                . "<th>Und.Medida</th>"
                . "<th>Cant.Medida</th>"
              . "</tr>"
            . "</thead>";
    //Abrimos un tbody para el nuevo grupo
    $tabla .= "<tbody>";

  }

  //creamos las columnas de la tabla
  foreach ($cab as $cup) {

    $tabla .= '<tr>';
    $tabla .= '<td>' . $cup['V010NOMBRE'] . '</td>';
    $tabla .= '<td>' . $cup['v012NOMBRE'] .  '</td>';
    $tabla .= '<td>' . round($cup['CANTIDAD_PRODUCTO_XINSUMO'])  . '</td>';;
    $tabla .= '</tr>';
  } 

}
//El ultimo grupo no va a cerrarse en el ciclo asi que lo cerramos aqui   
$tabla .= "</tbody>";

$tabla .= '</table>';

echo $tabla;
```